# How to replace a value of NameId with attribute in SimpleSAMLphp-based IdP?

Tags: php, docker, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to setup SimpleSAMLphp IdP to send a SAML response to my local dev server (SP-initiated flow in this case) . This IdP is based on a Docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/kristophjunge/test-saml-idp/  (ver. 1.15 I believe).

The whole setup is to emulate a similar environment that I have whereby G Suite IdP is used against the same local dev SP - trying to eventually eliminate the cloud dependency from my local dev environment and replace it with an equivalent SimpleSAMLphp one.

The problem I'm experiencing is Google sends NameId in its SAML response as this:

```
<saml2:Subject> 
    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">a.b@c.com</saml2:NameID> 
                  <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"> 
                     <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_88ebd953f02c07d01b19714cd70133827ff1228e" NotOnOrAfter="2018-05-07T20:21:25.433Z" .                         Recipient="https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/?acs" /> 
</saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml2:Subject>
```

but SimpleSAMLphp one instead sends it in this format:

```
<saml:Subject> 
<saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/metadata" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">_69d05500bd6e797de3674df0165facbfa0af699589</saml:NameID> 
<saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"> <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-05-09T17:47:57Z" Recipient="https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_170bb7a0ff82100318ba498583e8e59cdae8607b" /> 
</saml:SubjectConfirmation> 
</saml:Subject>
```

I need it to be an attribute value

(**a.b@c.com** instead of **_69d05500bd6e797de3674df0165facbfa0af699589**)

which I can then grab in my SP's logic, instead it sends some random number, I'm assuming it's a transientId.

Here are my configurations:

To start the Docker container:

```
docker run --name=testsamlidp_idp \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ENTITY_ID=https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/metadata \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE=https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/?acs  \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_SINGLE_LOGOUT_SERVICE=http://localhost/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/test-sp \
-v $(pwd)/users.php:/var/www/simplesamlphp/config/authsources.php \
-v $(pwd)/_saml20-sp-remote.php:/var/www/simplesamlphp/config/saml20-sp-remote.php \
-d kristophjunge/test-saml-idp
```

where **users.php** contains:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'core:AdminPassword',
    ),
    'example-userpass' => array(
        'exampleauth:UserPass',
        'user1:user1pass' => array(
            'uid' => array('1'),
            'Groups' => array('group1','group2', 'group3'),
            'email' => 'user1@example.com',
        ),
        'user2:user2pass' => array(
            'uid' => array('2'),
            'Groups' => array('group2', 'group4', 'group5'),
            'email' => 'user2@example.com',
        ),
    ),
);
```

and **_saml20-sp-remote.php** is:

```
<?php
/**
 * SAML 2.0 remote SP metadata for SimpleSAMLphp.
 *
 * See: https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-reference-sp-remote
 */
$metadata[getenv('SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ENTITY_ID')] = array(

    'AssertionConsumerService' => getenv('SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE'),
    'SingleLogoutService' => getenv('SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_SINGLE_LOGOUT_SERVICE'),

    #'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:persistent',
      #'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'email',
      #'simplesaml.attributes' => FALSE,

    'authproc.idp' => array(
            /* Filter to create a NameID with the "unspecified" format. */
            3 => array(
                'class' => 'saml:AtrributeNameID',
                'attribute' => 'email',
                'Format' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
            ),
        ),
        /* Select the unspecified NameID format by default. */
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',

);
```

I'm assuming it's some kind of a misconfiguration in the latter file, perhaps someone could lend me a hand in getting to the bottom of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is SimpleSAMLphp the idp or the SP in this context? What does the saml request XML look like? The request is generally where the preferred `NameIDFormat` is specified.

Comment: SimpleSAMLphp is an IdP.  Request should not be relevant as eventually (although not yet) we are planning to replace it with an IdP initiated SSO.  We are using the SP-initiated redirect now just for testing.

Comment: I don't know how an idp initiated flow would work, but are you sending Google and your test IdP identical saml requests? It's not irrelevant if you're trying to figure out why the two IdPs send different responses and you aren't sending the same request to both, or if you aren't specifying the preferred nameid format on both (or neither).

Comment: Yes, the requests are produced by the same code and hence identical.  I actually tried to specify the NameIdFormat in my SP configuration and it didn't make any difference.  The SP is Python based.  The IdP in this case is PHP on Docker and in Google case - it's a clould one, whatever they use internally.

Comment: For example, what do you get back in the response if you add `<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" />` to the SAML request?

Comment: Well, I don't have an ability to manually add that to the request as I'm using a framework, but as I mentioned, configuring that framework with a setting to that effect didn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Well hey, good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following setup worked for me:

### Docker startup script:

```
docker run --name=testsamlidp_idp \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ENTITY_ID=https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/metadata \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE=https://ee0138c4.ngrok.io/saml/?acs  \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_SINGLE_LOGOUT_SERVICE=http://localhost/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/test-sp \
-v $(pwd)/users.php:/var/www/simplesamlphp/config/authsources.php \
-v $(pwd)/saml20-idp-hosted.php:/var/www/simplesamlphp/metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php \
-d kristophjunge/test-saml-idp
```

### `saml20-idp-hosted.php` in `/var/www/simplesamlphp/metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php` in Docker container

```
<?php

$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
    /*
     * The hostname of the server (VHOST) that will use this SAML entity.
     *
     * Can be '__DEFAULT__', to use this entry by default.
     */
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',
    // X.509 key and certificate. Relative to the cert directory.
    'privatekey' => 'server.pem',
    'certificate' => 'server.crt',
    /*
     * Authentication source to use. Must be one that is configured in
     * 'config/authsources.php'.
     */
    'auth' => 'example-userpass',

  'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',


// refer to https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/saml:nameid
'authproc' => array(
  3 => array(
          'class' => 'saml:AttributeNameID',
          'attribute' => 'email',
          'Format' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
      ),
  ),

);
```

Both `NameIDFormat` and `Format` are necessary.  `email` should correspond to the attribute specified in

### `authsources.php` in `/var/www/simplesamlphp/config` of Docker container:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'core:AdminPassword',
    ),
    'example-userpass' => array(
        'exampleauth:UserPass',
        'user1:user1pass' => array(
            'uid' => array('1'),
            'Groups' => array('group1','group2', 'group3'),
            'email' => 'user1@example.com',
        ),
        'user2:user2pass' => array(
            'uid' => array('2'),
            'Groups' => array('group2', 'group4', 'group5'),
            'email' => 'user2@example.com',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The general idea on how to get to it is *somewhat [documented](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/saml:nameid)* 
but the documentation is not for the faint of heart and certainly welcomes sections on rationale of why things are the way they are.